# Issue with prerequisetes for wacom driver E: Unable to locate package linux-headers

Tags: drivers, kernel, wacom, crouton

Okay so before we begin I have installed ubuntu on my chromebook via crouton in developer mode. I am trying to install drivers on there for my wacom tablet (CTL-490) because chrome os doesn't support drivers or support the tablet by default.

I am using http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom as my guide however I am having issues with the first step for the prerequisites.

This is what I get back when putting in the command the guide gives me

> (xenial)foouser@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
>
> [sudo] password for foouser:
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.18.0-16395-ga6c1ef4067c9-dirty
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-3.18.0-16395-ga6c1ef4067c9-dirty'
>
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.18.0-16395-ga6c1ef4067c9-dirty'

I have looked around for a solution but nothing I've tried worked. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I looked through the packages for [Ubuntu-Xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/devel/) and don't see headers for kernel 3.18, and also checked [http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/) - it appears that this particular kernel version was not used by Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know where you got this particular kernel version from?

Comment: That tutorial is ancient, and kernel 3.8, is no longer supported. Wacom has integrated kernel support for ages now,  what happens when you simply try to plug in the tablet? Does it not work? if that is the case, maybe have a look at dmesg. command: $dmesg  see if the device comes up at all.

Comment: The kernel may have to do something with installing on my cromebook I used [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-install-ubuntu-chromebook-crouton) guide to install ubuntu. And as for dmesg [this](https://pastebin.com/UV1vvfnz) section mentions my tablet.

Comment: I looked into it some and according to [this](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1427) ubunutu on crouton seems to use the kernel on my computer that's used by chromeos.